# Liquid Shopify - Mobile Logo Width Not Taking from Settings

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I have a mobile logo separate from my desktop logo. I copied the code from the desktop logo and replicated the settings for the mobile logo, however, the logo size isn't being taken from the settings. It should be 250, whereas it's only 175. The logo image comes through from the settings just fine, it's the width that seems to be the only issue. Please see the screenshots and code below:

```
<a href="/" itemprop="url">
  {% capture image_size %}{{ section.settings.mobile_logo_max_width | escape }}x{% endcapture %}
  <img
       src="{{ section.settings.mobile_logo | img_url: image_size }}"
       srcset="{{ section.settings.mobile_logo | img_url: image_size }} 1x, {{ section.settings.mobile_logo | img_url: image_size, scale: 2 }} 2x"
       alt="{{ section.settings.mobile_logo.alt | default: shop.name }}"
       itemprop="mobile_logo"
   />
</a>

{
  "type": "image_picker",
  "id": "mobile_logo",
  "label": "Mobile Logo Image"
},
{
  "type": "text",
  "id": "mobile_logo_max_width",
  "label": "Mobile Logo Max Width (Pixels)",
  "default": "250"
}
```

[Front-End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyI7s.png)

[Back-End Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaCJZ.png)

Thanks for any insight you can offer.

Comment: Are you sure your logo width is at least 250px and not 170px, because I see the 250x setting in your img src, this means that the `img_url` is doing it's job, is the image width high enough in order to take that 250px width?

Comment: Hey @drip - The natural image width is 350 x 50. I'll try reuploading.